# Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit

Tags: java, jackson, retrofit

I want to get the raw http response from my API REST. I have tried with this interface:

```
@POST("/login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<retrofit.Response> login(@Field("username") String login, @Field("password") String pass,
                     @Field("appName") String appName, @Field("appKey") String appKey);
```

But I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
>   retrofit.Call
>       for method Api.login

I create `Retrofit` this way:

```
Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create());
Retrofit retrofitAdapter = retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
return retrofitAdapter.create(apiClass);
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To get access to the raw response, use `ResponseBody` from okhttp as your call type.

```
Call<ResponseBody> login(...)
```

In your callback, you can check the response code with the `code` method of the response.  This applies to any retrofit 2 return type, because your callback always gets a `Response` parameterized with your actual return type.  For asynchronous --

```
Call<ResponseBody> myCall = myApi.login(...)
myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // access response code with response.code()
        // access string of the response with response.body().string()
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

for synchronous calls --

```
Response<ResponseBody> response = myCall.execute();
System.out.println("response code" + response.code());
```

Comment: But this is the response body. What about if I want to check the http response code?

Comment: You will always get a `Response` object from which you can check the http code.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get the response object making request asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, sync vs async is no longer encoded in the interface.  You can decide on a per call basis.  `enqueue` as used above is asynchronous.  If you want it synchronous, you'd use `execute` with no callback -- Response<ResponseBody> myResponse = myCall.execute();

Comment: But I can't obtain the http response code from ResponseBody

Comment: You get the `Response` which has the http code.  How is it failing to get the code?

Comment: I get the Response in the asynchronous way, but not in the synchronous one. Maybe, I'm confused

Comment: synchronous case is easier -- added an example above.  If you are not seeing the print statement execute check to see if there is an exception thrown

Comment: @iagreen How will I fetch JSON response from ResponseBody?

Comment: response.body().string(): Cannot resolve method string

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though... OP asked how to get it with Retrofit, not OkHttp.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't want to change a lot of code and just want to log responses for some testing purpose, the answer by Rob Anderson below is the way to go.

Answer (score 42):

You can get information about headers, response code, down to raw json response body by using [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors). You can write your custom  Interceptors but I prefer to use Square's own Logging Interceptor. It's available on maven central.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

Here's how to use it

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

Logging level BODY will print headers to the body response. And in your Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)               
            .baseUrl("https://yourapi.com/api/")
            .build();
```

Now, open up Log Cat and you'll see raw HTTP response.

**Caution!**

**Don't forget to remove Interceptors (or change Logging Level to NONE) in production! Otherwise people will be able to see your request and response on Log Cat.**

Comment: can you tell me what's wrong with my code? becouse it doesnt work http://imgur.com/a/yKvfS

Comment: @zihadrizkyef : just in case, put your log level at "Verbose" in your LogCat

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but a different solution. I took the request and send it with OkHttp3Client. Like this:

```
//raw text 
Request request = call.clone().request();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
okhttp3.Response test = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(test.body().string());
```

source: http://robinhenniges.com/de/retrofit-2-raw-response

Comment: If only I'd seen this answer before changing all my code to handle `ResponseBody` type. Thank you sir

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved my day. Suggestion: I think its better if you use .string() inside a try catch block.

Comment: I tried something like this and the response body was an object name not a json response.  Am I doing something wrong?