# How to retrieve data from response? - Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

the response from the server as below:

```
{
    success: true,
    token: "someRandomToken"
}
```

How can I retrieve `token` from the response?

I tried to follow the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body) but I can't add generic to the `Call` inside onResponse `method`

**EDIT**

Here is my method

```
public void loginUser(final Context context, String url, String username, String passowrd, loginJson loginjson) {

        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        loginjson.setUsername(username);
        loginjson.setPassword(passowrd);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonFromForm = gson.toJson(loginjson);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonFromForm);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failure!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (context != null) {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(response.body() != null){

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
//
                } else {
                    if (context != null) {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.failed_to_login),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            }

        });


    }
```

After implementing @Piyush Patel answer:
I change the `Call` and the `Response` to `retrofit2.Call<tokenRetrieved>` and `retrofit2.Reponse<tokenRetrieved>` respectively. but the `Callback` in my `enqueue` prompt an error asking me to implement its `onResponse` and `onFailure` methods

newbie question: Am I using `retrofit1` methods?!!

Comment: First of all you are using okhttp for requesting API you need to import compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0' dependency in your app.gradle to use retrofit

Comment: @PiyushPatel whopps!!, thanks a lot man appreciate it

Comment: Its My pleasure..! if you have any query regarding retrofit just ask here I will respond you.

Comment: @PiyushPatel okay, thanks again :)

Comment: to parse data on response success does job for you with OkHttpClient
  if(response.body() != null){
   JsonResponse jsonResponse=gson.fromJson(response.body(), JsonResponse.class);
  }

Answer (score 4):

Here is a snippet that shows how you can implement it using GSON

```
public class JsonResponse {

    public String success;
    public String token;

    public JsonResponse(String success, String token) {
        this.success = success;
        this.token = token;
    }
}

Call<JsonResponse> call = api.checkLevel(1);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    JsonResponse jsonResponse=response.body();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: I get the following error when I add <T> to the call. "Type okhttp3.Callback does not have type parameter"

Comment: Show me what you have done? otherwise above snippet work perfectly for you.

Comment: You should use retrofit2.Callback instead of okhttp3.Callback. Check your imports

Answer (score 1):

### Using

> Volley u can do so

Try this code

```
public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                        if ((object.getBoolean("success"))==true){
                            String Token=object.getString("token");
                        }else{
                            // enter else condition
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    // json Exception

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `JSONObject` from your response string and to get the string with the key `token` use

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
json.getString("token");
```

Comment: if you have background about gson can I use it instead of JSONObject?, thanks !

Comment: Yes you can, plus GSON is more convenient for retrofit