# How to get resourceName and get parameter from given JSON in Retrofit?

Tags: android

```
{
    "title": "Flipkart Affiliate API Directory",
    "description": "This directory contains links for Product Feed API and Delta Feed API of all categories with all the versions available",
    "apiGroups": {
        "affiliate": {
            "name": "affiliate",
            "apiListings": {
                "food_nutrition": {
                    "availableVariants": {
                        "v1.1.0": {
                            "resourceName": "food_nutrition",
                            "put": null,
                            "delete": null,
                            "post": null,
                            "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/keshav/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1504895695325&sig=b25c6a83d531ef40377203de9ea148d3",
                            "deltaGet": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/deltaFeeds/keshav/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1504895695326&sig=c2cc339de1f7fabad8113d82428b837e",
                            "top": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/topFeeds/keshav/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1504895695326&sig=d66f64ee728f1978bc9cfd3a87ca4df3"
                        },
                        "v0.1.0": {
                            "resourceName": "food_nutrition",
                            "put": null,
                            "delete": null,
                            "post": null,
                            "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/feeds/keshav/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1504895695326&sig=8dd00a35f90d53e44b544a20b5215898",
                            "deltaGet": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/deltaFeeds/keshav/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1504895695326&sig=8dd00a35f90d53e44b544a20b5215898",
                            "top": null
                        }
                    },
                    "apiName": "food_nutrition"
                },
                "televisions": {
                    "availableVariants": {
                        "v1.1.0": {
                            "resourceName": "televisions",
                            "put": null,
                            "delete": null,
                            "post": null,
                            "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/keshav/category/ckf-czl.json?expiresAt=1504895695324&sig=8ddac7793632a7bba2923c414e89dc1e",
                            "deltaGet": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/deltaFeeds/keshav/category/ckf-czl.json?expiresAt=1504895695324&sig=8ddac7793632a7bba2923c414e89dc1e",
                            "top": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/topFeeds/keshav/category/ckf-czl.json?expiresAt=1504895695324&sig=56301eee9cc9c5d9504432868eeb97f3"
                        },
                        "v0.1.0": {
                            "resourceName": "televisions",
                            "put": null,
                            "delete": null,
                            "post": null,
                            "get": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/feeds/keshav/category/ckf-czl.json?expiresAt=1504895695324&sig=cea0487d37d2c906a698b73a7448950a",
                            "deltaGet": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/deltaFeeds/keshav/category/ckf-czl.json?expiresAt=1504895695324&sig=cea0487d37d2c906a698b73a7448950a",
                            "top": null
                        }
                    },
                    "apiName": "televisions"
                },




 }
        }
    }
}
String data = response.body().getAffiliate().getApiListings().getFoodNutrition().getAvailableVariants().getV110().getResourceName();
```

I am trying get List of resourceName and get for each ApiListings

I have all Model class but I don't know how I will get all resource name in one List and "get" in another value.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please help me in this Question

Comment: Are you sure this is the response that you are getting??

Comment: @TrueCall you should be adding one more node like getApiGroups() from which you can call getAffiliate()

Comment: @TrueCall...You can add GsonConvertor to reftrofit no?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

i have done this using parsing JSON object and JSON array ,take help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993886/7584651),

Comment: i did every thing     Fk-Affiliate-Id:affliatek
Fk-Affiliate-Token:98ccd7d7aa0c4b59a3f831d1db50f24e  this two thing i have to pass in header get method   @GET("api/keshav.json")
    Call<ApiGroups> getTopRatedProduct(@Header("Fk-Affiliate-Id") String AffiliateID, @Header("Fk-Affiliate-Token") String token);
 please chekc is it correct

Comment: response is not coming

Comment: See you have this response you only have to do is just get the parameter from this response ,is this you want?

Comment: I was doing the same way that you are doing i got more confusions and errors so by calling "ApiGroups" in your call method,i simply pass the object and this object will give the JSON response and in JSON response you can parse your data very easily.Try to pass my objects which i have passed in my example.

Comment: can u tell me how to send two Header parameter in getMethod in retrofit

Comment: before this i have same problem using volley but i dont  know how to do in retrofit . In volley i have send this one by one