# How to get list.size inside data object from server using retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 and here i am retrieving the data object from server which gives the list of objects present inside, how to know the size of the list. the list will provide objects so through those objects i can retrieve clients data in arrays.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "ClientName": "Shoib hasan",
        "CompanyName": "097676",
        "CityName": "Badin",
        "ContactNo": "sfgt",
        "TotalBalance": "11000.00",
        "AddedOn": "2017-07-18"
    }, {
        "ClientName": "Musakan Chappal",
        "CompanyName": "Muskan Chappal",
        "CityName": "Badin",
        "ContactNo": "",
        "TotalBalance": "15000.00",
        "AddedOn": "2017-07-18"
    }]
}
```

From Class Data i retrieve data object

```
Data data = response.body;
```

now get list size present inside data object

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("ClientName")
@Expose
private String clientName;
@SerializedName("CompanyName")
@Expose
private String companyName;
@SerializedName("CityName")
@Expose
private String cityName;
@SerializedName("ContactNo")
@Expose
private String contactNo;
@SerializedName("TotalBalance")
@Expose
private String totalBalance;
@SerializedName("AddedOn")
@Expose
private String addedOn;

public String getClientName() {
    return clientName;
}

public void setClientName(String clientName) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

public String getContactNo() {
    return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getTotalBalance() {
    return totalBalance;
}

public void setTotalBalance(String totalBalance) {
    this.totalBalance = totalBalance;
}

public String getAddedOn() {
    return addedOn;
}

public void setAddedOn(String addedOn) {
    this.addedOn = addedOn;
}

}
```

this is Example class

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data ;

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

this is method in activity

```
 public void fetch_information(String CityId) {
    this.CityID = CityId;
    ApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);
    Call<Example> call = ApiInterface.GetClients(CityID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            data = new Example();
              data.setData(response.body().getData());

             Integer clientlist_size = response.body().getData().size();


            prepareClientsData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
public void prepareClientsData() {

clients = new String[data.getData().size()];
    for(int i = 0; i<data.getData().size();i++){
        clients[i] = data.getData().get(i).getClientName();

    }
    client_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EzKhataActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clients);

    client_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout);
    client_spinner.setAdapter(client_adapter);
```

this is i am getting

[image: image for data object on response body]

Comment: whats your `Data` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use these 2 class as your response class**

> Datum.class

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("ClientName")
@Expose
private String clientName;
@SerializedName("CompanyName")
@Expose
private String companyName;
@SerializedName("CityName")
@Expose
private String cityName;
@SerializedName("ContactNo")
@Expose
private String contactNo;
@SerializedName("TotalBalance")
@Expose
private String totalBalance;
@SerializedName("AddedOn")
@Expose
private String addedOn;

public String getClientName() {
return clientName;
}

public void setClientName(String clientName) {
this.clientName = clientName;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getCityName() {
return cityName;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
this.cityName = cityName;
}

public String getContactNo() {
return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getTotalBalance() {
return totalBalance;
}

public void setTotalBalance(String totalBalance) {
this.totalBalance = totalBalance;
}

public String getAddedOn() {
return addedOn;
}

public void setAddedOn(String addedOn) {
this.addedOn = addedOn;
}

}
```

> Result.class

```
public class Result{

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

**Use `Result class` in your Retrofit Interface as signature.**

**And use `response.body().getData().size()` for the number of object in list.**

**Go through [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body/40973753#40973753) for more explanations.**

Comment: data = new Example();
                  data.setData(response.body().getData());
               Integer   clientlist_size = response.body().getData().size();                                        this gives data Arraylist size 0;

Comment: what is example ?

Comment: Example is a class in Retrofit Interface as signature just like you mentioned Result class above i.e data= new Result(); data.setData(response.body().getData()); i am getting response as data object but it is null.

Comment: i did post most of it also image will show what i am getting.

Comment: just check your url with postman ??  we can't see any problem in code?

Comment: will you share your url after `.com` ??

Comment: check your cityId while debuging ??

Comment: the problem was not the code it was working fine the issue was in Api interface i was passing @POST("ClientsInCity")                                                                               Call<Example> GetClients(@Query"city" String CityId);                                             instead it should be                                                                                                       Call<Example> GetClients(@Field"city" String CityId);

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the response to jsonobject and get the json array size like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) response.body();
JsonArray result = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("data");
int size = result.size();
```