# How to parse below json in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Welcome jaymin",
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "jaymin",
        "email": "jaymin@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "123456"
    }
}

Comment: Do we really need Retrofit 2 to parse Json?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993886/7584651

Comment: @Toaster : We can use

Answer (score 1):

you can add GsonFactory or can JacksonFactory in creating retrofit service
    and can use this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ 
to create a pojo class through which you can parse data. I have converted your JSON into Gson format java class which you can use in android to parse data.

```
   -----------------------------------com.example.Data.java----------------------- 
   ------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("mobile")
@Expose
private String mobile;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getMobile() {
return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
this.mobile = mobile;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.FollowersResponse.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class FollowersResponse {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

Comment: I have used this before..But i am always getting null in onresponse method

Comment: Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
             Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);


you have to add the line addConverterFactory() in creation of retrofit  @JaiminThakkar and have to add this dependency in gradle:-
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

Comment: I have also use that

Comment: Can you share the proper code where you are facing problem?
I can tell you the exact solution after that only.

Comment: public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

This is my builder class

Comment: ok how you are using it in your code while fetching the data ? 
I mean to say How you are making a network call ?

Comment: I have got null pointer error  for this @SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String exapense.roommate.com.retrofitjava.modal.LoginResponse.getName()' on a null object reference

Comment: There can be two cases here :-
Either your data is coming null from the server or your data key is changed to another name .

Comment: LoginResponse class is your Data class ?? @JaiminThakkar

Comment: Got the solution mate.. Defined the constuctor in pojo class and got the solution @abhishek sharma

Answer (score 0):

To phrase your string to a JSONObject you do the following

```
String jsonString = '{ "status": true, "message": "Welcome jaymin", "data": { "id": 1, "name": "jaymin", "email": "jaymin@gmail.com", "mobile": "123456" } }'
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString)
```

Then you can retrieve values from the JSONObject like so

```
String message = jsonObj.get("message") //Message = "Welcome jaymin"
```