# How to get (@GET) JSON Array response using retrofit

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on an app in which I am using REST APIs for data exchanges.My back-end scripts are in PHP, in one of my module I am sending as JSON response from back-end
to Android client and fetching it at Android side using retrofit with @GET annotation.

Below is my JSON which I want to accept.

```
[
    [
        {
            "column_name": "email"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "product_code"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "column_value": "ht@t.com"
        },
        {
            "column_value": "BBAN0003"
        }
   ]
]
```

**Below is my retrofit interface,**

```
@GET("testing/getProductdetails.php") 
Call<JSONArray> getColumnNames(@Query("email") String email);
```

The error I was getting is

> expected begin object but was begin array

**My PHP back-end code**

```
<?php 

 /*
 * Created by Belal Khan
 * website: www.simplifiedcoding.net 
 * Retrieve Data From MySQL Database in Android
 */

 //database constants
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USER', 'id6935081_pksinghhps');
 define('DB_PASS', 'kingmessi10');
 define('DB_NAME', 'id6935081_users');

 //connecting to database and getting the connection object
 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

 //Checking if any error occured while connecting
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();
 }
 if(isset($_GET['email']))
{
     $email=$_GET["email"];

 $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS from product_details";
if (($result = $conn->query($sql)) == true) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $sub[] = $row[0];


    }
}
      $column_value = array();

      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM product_details WHERE email = '".$email."' ";
       if (($result2 = $conn->query($sql2)) == true) {
           while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()){
          for($j=0;$j<sizeof($sub);$j++){
           $sub2 = array();    
           $sub2["column_value"] = $row2[$j];
           array_push($column_value,$sub2);
          }

       }
       }

       else echo "NO";


 $events = array(); 
 $k=0;
 while($k<sizeof($sub)){
     $temp = array();
     $temp['column_name']= $sub[$k];
     array_push($events, $temp);
     $k++;

 }


     $main = array();
     array_push($main,$events);
     array_push($main,$column_value);
     echo json_encode($main);


}
?>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body

Comment: @prashant17 that was not what i want, My response is different and i trying to GET data

Comment: Try Call<List<Response[]>> where Response is your data model.

Comment: just go through the steps in answer you will get what you want. You need to modify it to your need

Comment: create a pojo class using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and `@GET("testing/getProductdetails.php") 
Call<....Your pojo class...> getColumnNames(@Query("email") String email);`

Comment: In my data model / pojo class do i need to define them as                                          private  JSONArray coulmn_name;   ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change

```
Call<List<List<Map>>>
```

Comment: I have send Java files to you on mail check it

Comment: And make call as like this Call<Data>

Comment: hwy thanks, i checked them but there is one problem the class Row can vary. I mean my columns like email supplier etc can vary I adding them dynamically while saving them ....so this class row will create problems in future

Comment: Remove class row and use Map in Data file instead of Row

Comment: Updated on main

Comment: hey thanks, but I was asking how do i get this data from my on response method , simply by doing ...

Comment: Make your call like this Call<Data>

Comment: And search about Hashmap its so easy and usefull

Comment: Call<PVModel> getColumnNames(@Query("email") String email);

Comment: my call i just changed the name of class

Comment: pvmodel.getColumns() will return list of columns

Comment: hey Akash thank you for all your help, your efforts worked like a charm , you saved my brain from a blast. I am really newbie to php that is why that response was a chaos thank you for changing it. THANK YOU FOR THE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

Entity to hold your actual data:

```
class JsonColumnNameHolder {
    @SerializedName("column_name")
    private final String myField;
    @SerializedName("column_value")
    private final String myField2;

    public JsonColumnNameHolder(String myField, String myField2) {
        this.myField = myField;
        this.myField2 = myField2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return myField;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return myField2;
    }
}
```

Retrofit signature:

```
@GET("testing/getProductdetails.php") 
Single<List<List<JsonColumnNameHolder>>> getColumnNames(@Query("email") String email);
```

Comment: how to get data in my fragment class ??

Comment: `yourRetrofiService.getColumnNames(",,,").subscribe(...)`

Comment: by using this i will not get all the values of my array , i think it will throw error again because the column_name and value are in array

Comment: It's fairly broad topic, pls check here for example https://android.jlelse.eu/making-your-rxjava-intentions-clearer-with-single-and-completable-f064d98d53a8 (just first link I stumbled upon). I would definitely recommend going rx path as it is pretty standard way of doing async ops these days. You will have to add couple of dependencies to your gradle in order to use it, in particular this one https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava