# how to get data from Retrofit Response with String msg and JsonObject

Tags: android

Get data from Retrofit Response which contain String msg and JsonObject and JsonArray

```
server Response{
        "msg": "code is valid",
        "productInfo": {
            "name": "AC",
            "description": "Product AC",
            "companyName": "MITSUBISHI",
            "brandName": "MITSUBISHI",
            "batchNumber": "123131131",
            "serialNumber": "12132133232222",
            "manufactureDate": "2019-10-11T09:47:33.425Z",
            "expireDate": "2019-10-11T09:47:33.425Z",
            "otherAttributes": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "power",
                    "fieldType": "electricity",
                    "fieldValue": "1200W"
                }, ]}}
```

Comment: please help me I have alot of code but it not solve

Comment: Please provide what have you tried so far

Comment: @GET("/json-data")
    Call<ServerResponse> getJsonData();

Comment: sendRequest.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ServerResponse response2 = response.body();

Comment: I have try this code

Comment: post in your question not in comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40973753/10182897 Please read this answer carefully this will help you properly to understand the how to work with retrofit.

Comment: I already this link but it not help

Comment: can you post the model class and also implementation of Api call?

Comment: i have model same hava variable like msg and productinfo array