# How to make a simple http post request in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android. I do have some experience with java, but can not solve this problem for some time.

Here is some background information: 
I am trying to make a mobile application, which picks an image from the gallery or camera then send it to my server. I am done with picking the image, converting it to base64, but somehow I can not complete the function for http post request. I want this function to return the response from the server, but I am failing.

I have highlighted a part of the function with a comment. The part I do not understand is Overridden methods. As I said, I am a beginner and Android Studio made me include these methods(OnResponse, OnFailure), with these methods I can not return the response because they are void; and without these methods I am having an exception which I have no clue where it is coming from.

```
public void postRequest(String postdata) throws IOException {
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        String url = "https://ptsv2.com/t/z497u-xxx/post";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postdata);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        //THIS IS THE PART I DO NOT UNDERSTAND
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                message = response.body().string();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `enqueue` function performs the network access on a background thread. Therefore the result is not immediately available to you. To receive the result you must pass in an instance of `Callback`. When the request finishes in the other thread OkHttp will call the `onResponse` function of your callback instance. If the request failed it will call `onFailure`.

If you need the result in the calling thread and block until the result is available you can use the `execute()` method of the call class. Note that this will not work on the main thread in Android as network access is not allowed there.

Comment: It is my exact problem I think. I have picked the image in main thread, so I have tried execute() in main, but had an exception as you said. How can I solve it? I am not familiar with the thread concept...

Comment: It's quite difficult to give a good answer to this question because I don't know your code base. A simple approach would be to start some form of loading indicator, then call the `enqueue` function and when the `onResponse` or `onFailure` function is called you would stop the loading indicator and process/display the result.

Answer (score 0):

> [Retrofit 2: Get JSON from Response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body/45898548#45898548)

Go through above link if you want to post then just pass parameter to interface like mentioned follow

in api interface write

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("append_url")
Call<CompanyDetailsResponse> getCompanyDetails(@Field("para") String para);
```

and use

```
Call<CompanyDetailsResponse> call = apiService.getCompanyDetails("para");
```

instead of

```
Call<CompanyDetailsResponse> call = apiService.getCompanyDetails();
```

and use model class according to your json response and drop comment if any query