# How to get data from nested JSON objects using Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, deserialization

I would like get countynames from the API and it returns  nested objects;

```
"countries": {
    "1": {
        "name": "Cyprus",
        "nameTurkish": "KKTC",
        "nameNative": "Kıbrıs"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Turkey",
        "nameTurkish": "Türkiye",
        "nameNative": "Türkiye"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Monaco",
        "nameTurkish": "Monako",
        "nameNative": "Monaco"
    },
```

and so on there are more than 200 countries and every county has its own "NUMBER_ID". In the end I want to list all "name" information. I think I should use JsonDeserializer but unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: get all keys from countries json object and use for loop to get and save name of each country in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire JSON response can be read as a `JSONObject` that has multiple elements in it that you can iterate through and get different data.

```
String jsonResponse = ""; // Put the entire JSON response as a String 
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

JSONArray rootArray = root.getJSONArray("countries"); // root element of the json respons

for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject number = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String country = number.getString("name"); // Get country name

    // Here you can add `country` into a List
}
```

UPDATE:

> but there is no array in my JSON file, all of them are objects, every
>   country is in an object and every object has its own SerializedName

You can read it into JSONOjbect, and instead of using a JSONArray, you can iterate over the length of the JSONObject as below.

```
try {
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    JSONObject countries = root.getJSONObject("countries");

    for (int i = 1; i <= countries.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject number = countries.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
        String country = number.getString("name"); // Get country name

        // Here you can add the `country` into a List
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hello, but there is no array in my JSON file, all of them are objects, every country is in an object and every object has its own SerializedName

Comment: @Ahmet thanks for notifying this, I have modified the answer with `UPDATE` section, and it worked for your given JSON.. hope it can help

Comment: thank you @Zain , your edited model works well when I put the data into Asset folder. However my JSON data is in API and I want to get it using retrofit, can you give me an advice?

Comment: @Ahmet you're most welcome .. please have look at [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body/40973772), and especially the online tool that will help you automatically create your pojo & retrofit classes

Answer (score 0):

try using TypeToken.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<Country> list = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(what_you_get_data), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Country>>(){}.getType()); //Country is VO class what you make.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can see that your data looks like `HashMap`, so I just tried in that way and your data parsed successfully without a glitch:

1. Create Pojo's:

   ```
   public class Countries {
       private HashMap<String, Country> countries;
       public HashMap<String, Country> getCountries() { return countries; }

       public void setCountries(HashMap<String, Country> countries) { this.countries = countries; }
   }

   public class Country {
       private String name;
       private String nameTurkish;
       private String nameNative;

       public String getName() { return name; }
       public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
       public String getNameTurkish() { return nameTurkish; }
       public void setNameTurkish(String nameTurkish) { this.nameTurkish = nameTurkish; }
       public String getNameNative() { return nameNative; }
       public void setNameNative(String nameNative) { this.nameNative = nameNative; }
   }
   ```
2. Create a Gson Object and parse it:

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();

       // Countries Object
       Type testC = new TypeToken<Countries>(){}.getType();
       Countries ob = gson.fromJson(test, testC);
       String newData = gson.toJson(ob.getCountries());

       System.out.println("New Data: "+newData);

       // All country in HashMap
       Type country = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Country>>(){}.getType();
       HashMap<String, Country> countryHashMap = gson.fromJson(newData, country);

       // Print All HashMap Country
       for (Map.Entry<String, Country> set : countryHashMap.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println("==> "+set.getKey() + " = " + set.getValue());
       }
   ```
3. Output:

   ```
   I/System.out: ==> 1 = Country{name='Cyprus', nameTurkish='KKTC', nameNative='Kıbrıs'}
   I/System.out: ==> 2 = Country{name='Turkey', nameTurkish='Türkiye', nameNative='Türkiye'}
   I/System.out: ==> 3 = Country{name='Monaco', nameTurkish='Monako', nameNative='Monaco'}
   ```

Comment: I already have looked at it. There is a constant "content" object, but in my example every country has its own SerializedName