# Login API Android API KEY authentifiaction

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, api-key

i am developing android application in Java
i use native authentification for the login with the API KEY.
username and password encoded base 64 :  key: MAXAUTH value: nom:password(encoded 64)
and the response is as cookie (set-cookies) header
Someone can help me with code How can i do combine the username and password in base64 and use them then how can i use the set-cookie

Comment: Check out this tutorial for adding headers in retrofit. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question can be divided into two parts:-

1. Encode Username and Password into base64
2. Send Login Request and handle response

Please refer to these guide

- [Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code)
- [Consuming APIs with Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit)
- [Retrofit 2: Get JSON from Response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body)

**1. Encode Username and Password into base64**

```
private String encodeToBase64(String username, String password) {

    String text = username + ":" + password;

    byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return base64;
}
```

**2. . Send Login Request and handle response**

Create the retrofit instance

```
// Trailing slash is needed
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.myservice.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

Define the endpoints

```
public interface Api {
    // Request method and URL specified in the annotation

    @POST("login")
    Call<ResponseBody> loginUser(
        @Header("MAXAUTH") String apiKey
    );
}
```

Consume the endpoint

```
String username = "...";
String password = "...";

String base64APIKey = encodeToBase64(username, password);

Call<Result> call = api.loginUser(base64APIKey);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) { 
     if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        response.body(); // have your all data
        
        // Handle Success Response

    } else {
        response.errorBody(); // Has your error response body
        
        // Handle Error Response
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
        // Handle Network Errors or Exceptions here.
    }
});
```

***Word of caution:-*** Base64 is not an encryption method, its an encoding method and can be decoded. This means your API_KEY can easily be decoded and username/password can easily be extracted thus making it insecure.

Comment: Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean **Basic Authentication**.

If so then all you need is the **Authorization header** with the value being the Base64 encoded **username:password** combo prefixed with the string **"Basic "**
For example if the **username is foo** and the **password is bar** then the Base64 encoded string is **Zm9vOmJhcg==** so you would pass the header **Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==** as part of your request.

Also could you share a code snippet of how you're currently doing it?

Comment: No i use native authentification: for headers: key: MAXAUTH and value: username:password(encoded64)

Comment: in postman i use API KEY and not basic authentification