# Retrofit 2 GET request returns html instead of JSON

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit2

I am a newbie to retrofit and I am trying to call a GET request to the URL https://www.instagram.com/p/CQiocPoNqTw/?__a=1 using Retrofit 2, The request works fine on browser and postman. but it won't work with retrofit 2. I have attached the screenshot of my logcat.

[image]

The request is implemented as

```
    @Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
    )
    @GET
    suspend fun getPostInfo(@Url url : String) : Response<PostDetails>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does response html include? Did it resolved your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body

Comment: i think you url is wrong. check base Url and 'getPostInfo()'  Method initialize Url

Comment: @SandeepPareek Check the logs, its requesting to the correct url

Comment: @Muhtar it's IG Auth Page

Comment: sometimes this url redirecting me to login page after login the json will there if this will target login then you will get html obviously

Comment: if the user is not logged this will returns html

Comment: yes you should search for authenticated api call

Comment: Then why is this working without auth in postman as well as browser?

Comment: test your request in postman if you get html in postman to , then your API is problem . also you can use postman to set header value to application/json and see your result

Comment: This works perfectly fine on postman and web browser @Erfan