# Get json from request body by gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

How I can get json request body?

```
   App.getApi().method(data).enqueue(new Callback<Obj>() {
        @Override 
        public void onResponse(Call<Obj> call, Response<Obj> response){
             // print here 
        }
        ...
   };
```

Comment: add your api response also

Comment: response code 200

Comment: Would that be inside the data object?

Comment: Log.e("response : ",  new Gson().toJson(response.body()) );

Comment: add this below print here

Comment: I mean, you're really talking about a body "sent" to the request or "retrieved" from its response?

Comment: I have some format trouble in my json data. I need saw what I send to server.

Comment: it's already explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45993886/9181430

Comment: Do not finded there how cast request (json) body to json string. I need see that gson do with strings inside my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to print request / response while using retrofit you can enable logging check this [article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses) for same.