# How to get raw json response of Retrofit in Kotlin?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit, http-get

I am new to `Kotlin` and `Retrofit`. I want to call a base `URL` through `Retrofit` and print the raw `JSON` response. What would be the simplest minimal configuration?

Let's say,

```
base url = "https://devapis.gov/services/argonaut/v0/" 
method = "GET"
resource = "Patient"
param = "id"
```

I tried,

```
val patientInfoUrl = "https://devapis.gov/services/argonaut/v0/"

        val infoInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            val newUrl = chain.request().url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .query(accountId)
                    .build()

            val newRequest = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .url(newUrl)
                    .header("Authorization",accountInfo.tokenType + " " + accountInfo.accessToken)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .build()

            chain.proceed(newRequest)
        }

        val infoClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(infoInterceptor)
                .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(patientInfoUrl)
                .client(infoClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        Logger.i(TAG, "Calling retrofit.create")
        try {
            // How to get json data here
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Logger.e(TAG, "Error", e);
        }
        Logger.i(TAG, "Finished retrofit.create")

    }
```

How can i get the raw json output. I don't want to implement user data class and parsing stuffs if possible. Is there any way?

#### Update 1

Marked duplicated post ([Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282889/get-raw-http-response-with-retrofit)) is not for Kotlin and I need Kotlin version.

Comment: If you only want to print the response then why not use `HttpLogIntercepter`? To Get raw response [Follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282889/get-raw-http-response-with-retrofit) ..

Comment: @ADM I did not know about `HttpLogIntercepter`.

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar This is in java and I am working on Kotlin.

Comment: You can convert it.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Here is a Doc illustrating about logging with a one liner code .. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses.. If you are having problem with Kotlin Syntax then you can write it in java and later covert it in Kotlin then Understand the syntax ..

Comment: `Marked duplicated post (Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit) is not for Kotlin and I need Kotlin version.` then convert it. I like how your bio says "problem solver" yet you rely on others to convert Java code to Kotlin **for you**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282889/get-raw-http-response-with-retrofit)

Comment: @rafid059 please read my post carefully until the end.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is pretty easy you just need to make your network calls function like this.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Your URL")
fun myNetworkCall() : Call<ResponseBody>
```

The point here is your network call should return a `Call` of type `ResponseBody`. And from `ResponseBody` you can get the response in String format.

Now when you will call this function to perform the network call you will get the raw string response.

```
    MyApi().myNetworkCall().enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseBody>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            //handle error here
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            //your raw string response
            val stringResponse = response.body()?.string()
        }

    })
```

Its pretty simple. Let me know if you want any other details. Hope this helps. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the response body of okhttp as retrofit is based on okhttp.

Here is an example which you can convert to your use case:

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<ResponseBody> getUser(@Path("user") String user);
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> myCall = getUser(...)
myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // access response code with response.code()
        // access string of the response with response.body().string()
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

For more information see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286112/4428159

Comment: My question was for Kotlin

Comment: What do you mean by `getUser(...)`

Comment: You can easily convert Java code to kotlin or you can directly use java code in kotlin as well.

Comment: getUser(...) is the implementation of the interface which I defined in first step.

Comment: Could you please update your answer for Kotlin. I am not getting your getUser. Could you please post the implementation also. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with kotlin. See if this helps you https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890

Comment: Your link asking to switch me for premium medium account :(.

Comment: try in private browser window.

Comment: `response.body().string()` does not print the json rathe printing class id, `okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@88eab56`

Comment: In my case for printing the json string and only that, I have to use JsonObject instead of ResponseBody everywhere, and use response.body().toString()