# Retrofit: Raw response body from a gson converted body

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I am using the following libraries for retrofit.

```
'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
```

How can I get the raw response in onResponse callback? I already searched for it and got a lots of solutions which doesn't help now. I tried `response.raw().body.string()` and `response.body().source().toString()` which throws can not read body from a converted body. I also tried `response.body().string()` but in this case `.string()` is unresolved. I can log the response using interceptor but I need that response in my `onResponse()` callback, not just printing in logcat.
My Retrofit Client:

```
public static ApiService getClient(Context context) {

    if (retrofit == null) {
        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equalsIgnoreCase("dev")){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }else {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(SelfSigningClientBuilder.createClient(context))
                    .build();
        }

    }
    return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

My Retyrofit Interface:

```
@retrofit2.http.POST("weekly_driver_earning_report/")
@retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded
Call<List<DailyEarnings>> getDriverWeeklyEarnings(@retrofit2.http.Field("access_token") String access_token, @retrofit2.http.Field("start_date") String start_date, @retrofit2.http.Field("end_date") String end_date);
```

Comment: Post your retrofit interface. Also, use consistent library versions. Retrofit 2.5.0 depends on okhttp > 3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282889/get-raw-http-response-with-retrofit)

Comment: I think one has to remove the ORM auto-mapping to get the `Call<ResponseBody>` in there.

Comment: I have added interface code snippets @sonnet

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have mentioned earlier that response.body().string() is not available now

Comment: You have to change `Call<List<DailyEarnings>>` into `Call<ResponseBody>` to get the whole http response in the callback.

Comment: @sonnet I have changed my okhttp from okhttp:2.7.5 to okhttp3:4.2.0 and replaced my model class to ResponseBody but still getting the same error `onResponse: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.`

Comment: Plese put the error also. If your json response is not validated GsonConverterFactory will not able to deserialize instead use scalar converter factory in retrofit to print raw response.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule my onResponse works fine in other statements, I am getting proper views, so I have a Validated Json, also checked it in Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286112/5339146), I solved my problem later. I defined my Call type to specific model class and that's why response.body().string() was inaccessible, Changing my Call type from List to ResponseBody, I could access response.body().string().